# Unexpected union distribution

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

What do I need to do to be able to assign `b` to `a`?

```
let a: DecideApi<ScaleToThree>;
let b = { kind: 'IsAny' as const, what: new Set<ScaleToThree>() } ;
let c: ScalarApi<ScaleToThree>

a = b; // Type '1' is not assignable to type '3'
c = b; // no problem



type ScaleToThree = 1|2|3;
type ScalarApi<T extends ScalarType>
  = { kind: 'IsAny', what: Set<T> }
type CollectionApi<T extends ScalarType>
  = { kind: 'HasAll', what: Set<T> }


type DecideApi<T> =
  T extends CollectionType<infer K>
    ? CollectionApi<K>
    : T extends ScalarType
    ? ScalarApi<T>
    : never;
type CollectionType<T extends ScalarType> = Array<T> | Set<T>
type ScalarType = string | number
```

I'm guessing the problem is inside the `DecideApi<T>`, but I don't have an idea of how to mitigate this.

Here's a [TypeScript Playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/FAGwpgLgBAhgXFAImAxgSwCZgIIAc0A8AyijOACoD25AFgE5hgB8A3KJFAEZQC8UA3lADWaAHYYEAcgCSAZ2yiAnpNiyoKSqNkQANFADuNGBASiw+qEUjFSFavUZMAFAEooAXyhtw0FAhJkMHR4hAF2tAzMwMAwvFxsKHGcbNHAEIq4YJa2YFQRjHEAjAA+AEzFAMxs6ZnZgcH4BORQYAAeEGDiamFB5BlRUHGCIuJScgrKeobG-tbkTB5p-VAAwpQg4CgQaJohTS3tnRjdtr39TMCDfMNiElCSABIw8huSU0YmlnML7qk1Wch0Fg9vNeJcoM02h0uqt1pttpo+pkCGIAGZgOhQADSF0GgwA-LCNqgEaI9jjwYMEJDDjCenQkWBKVBCfSQbi8aYwAA3DHVZZrYlbHaiRn7KFHE71RkLPjYOh0GCKJoLYpfCAqpa1emMuLaOhiADmUDVogArgBbTgY6JAA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prevent the distribution from happening by using square brackets inside your conditional types:

```
type DecideApi<T> =
  [T] extends [CollectionType<infer K>]
    ? CollectionApi<K>
    : [T] extends [ScalarType]
    ? ScalarApi<T>
    : never;
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/FAGwpgLgBAhgXFAImAxgSwCZgIIAc0A8AyijOACoD25AFgE5hgB8A3KJFAEZQC8UA3lADWaAHYYEAcgCSAZ2yiAnpNiyoKSqNkQANFADuNGBASiw+qEUjFSFavUZMAFAEooAXyhtw0FAhJkMHR4hAF2tAzMwMAwvFxsKHGcbMAQirhglrZgVBGMcQCMAD4ATEUAzGxpGVmBwfgE5FBgAB4QYOJqYUHk6VFQcYIi4lJyCsp6hsb+1uRMHql9UADClCDgKBBomiGNzW0dGF22PX1MwAN8Q2ISUJIAEjDy65KTRiaWs-Pu0Ys1yOgsLs5rwLlAANrkAC6+3anQhq3WqC2ml6GQIYgAZmA6FAANJMKFggYAfhWaw2KNEuwJxKgCEhMNacKOEO6dDRYCJA1JtRAQWB5x59KgZgAbjiUtVMojKdtRJy9szDsc6pz5nxsHQ6DBFI15kVPhB9X9MuzOXFtHQxABzKCG0QAVwAtpwcdEgA)

If you're interested in why it works, head over to TypeScript documentation on [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types).